# Перенос строки в strings.xml

Tags: java, android

Как сделать в `strings.xml` перенос строки?

Comment: не могли бы более подробно описать проблему

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Пример:

```
<string name="foo_string">
  Первая строка \n
  Вторая строка \n
  Третья строка  
</string>
```